# Lazy property getting value before first get

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, abstract-class, lazy-initialization

In the beginning, there was code:

```
public abstract class A
{
    private string _someValue;

    public string SomeValue
    {
        get
        {
            if (_someValue == null)
                _someValue = GetValue();
            return _someValue;
        }
    }

    protected virtual string GetValue() { /* logic */ }
}

public class B : A
{
    protected override string GetValue()
    {
        return base.GetValue() + GetMoreValue();
    }

    private string GetMoreValue() { /* logic */ }
}
```

And the code said, "Let there be bugs!" and there were bugs.

---

Seriously now.

I have an instance of `B`, and when I get `SomeValue`, I get the same `SomeValue` of `A`, without the MoreValue.

The even weirder part came when I put a breakpoint on `SomeValue`'s Get method:
It turns out that `_someValue` gets its value *before the Get method is ever called*.

Something is very wrong here.

---

UPDATE:
Thanks for the comments! Shortened code, and added forgotten return type in B method.

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Make your code compile (B.GetValue() needs a return type; A.GetValue() and B.GetMoreValue() needs initialized return) then debug your example and you'll see that it works as expected (B.SomeValue contains both of your values).
My bet is that the bug that you are hunting is somewhere in the left out code - so you already made a very important step to locate it.

Comment: I test it it works well, the `GetMoreValue` of B is called. Did I miss something?

Comment: What does `GetMoreValue();` return? Set a breakpoint and check that it isn't an empty string - would give the appearance of `SomeValue` being the same as `A`

Comment: Are you debugging and have you configured the debugger to automatically retrieve property values? If the debugger automatically reads `SomeValue`, `_someValue` will get set.

Comment: @hvd How do I do that?

Comment: @JacobSpire That's the "Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls" setting in VS, Tools, Options, Debugging, General.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was making a stupid mistake.
(I would delete the question, but I figured others can learn from my blooper.)

**I had a watch on `SomeValue`.**

The result? `Get SomeValue` was called the moment I started debugging.
(Which is a little weird, because I had a breakpoint on the `Get` method which didn't activate. For some reason, `watch`es don't trigger breakpoints.)

*(As for the wrong value, that had nothing to do with inheritance -
`GetMoreValue` simply happened to return an empty string.)